# Google visualization table not allowing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am using the Google visualization tools to show a table, but all of my HTML is being shown as a string.  Here is the code:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
data.setTableProperty('allowHtml', true)

data.addColumn('string','Keyword')
data.addColumn('number','<img src="http://m8app.com/assets/google-icon-8556487cd6ff3508d7bf2c4f64a0e3ad.jpg">Rank')
data.addColumn('number','Rank Change')
data.addColumn('string','Page')
data.addColumn('string','Link')

var row = 1;
while(row < thing.length){
data.addRow([
thing[row][0],
parseInt(thing[row][1],10),
parseInt(thing[row][2],10),
thing[row][3],
"<a href='"+thing[row][4]+"' target='_blank'>Search</a>"]);
row++;
}



    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('rankInner'));
    table.draw(data, {
    allowHtml:true,
    showRowNumber: false, 
    page : 'enable', 
    pageSize:10, 
    sortColumn: 2, 
    sortAscending:false
    });
```

I have set 'allowHtml' to true on both the DataTable and the Table, but the table still shows the full text of the HTML rather than rendering it as html. I'd be grateful for any recommendation to try, thank you.

Comment: What you have now is the javascript, and as such if you run you should get empty page : http://jsfiddle.net/6QFsA/ . Are you referrencing the required libraries to call `new google.visualization.Table` ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not include the entire page.  There is a div called rankInner and I have imported the visualization library.  This code is being called successfully and I am successfully creating the table, however the places where I use html (in one of the column headers and in all of column 4) they are appearing in the table as a block of HTML code rather than an image and a link, respectively.

Comment: should work . i tried one in the online editor which i will share below

Comment: feel free to accept as answer if that works

Comment: The only thing I actually see wrong with your actual code is that the docs don't seem to suggest that `data.setTableProperty('allowHtml', true)` is supported.  Please correct me if I'm wrong (it happens sometimes).

Comment: You are correct.  I had been trying to set 'allowHtml' to true on virtually everything (the data table, the table, and even the individual cells in the table) and that was a remnant of one I had tried.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a sample like yours in the online visualization playground, and it seems good

The only line I see you got messed up is the below line, where the indentation is wrong [quotes, double quotes. Compare with the below working one]

```
"<a href='"+thing[row][4]+"' target='_blank'>Search</a>"]);
```

link : https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#table

Code I tried:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Height', 'Dance'],
    ['Kuttappan', 174, true],
    ['Raayappan', 523, false],
    ["<a href='abc.com' target='_blank'>Search</a>", 86, true]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  visualization.draw(data,  {allowHtml:true});
}
```

when you run it [click on RunCode in the tool], you see the search link, and not the HTML code.

The below code for image,

```
data.addColumn('number','<img src="http://m8app.com/assets/google-icon-8556487cd6ff3508d7bf2c4f64a0e3ad.jpg">Rank')
```

is indeed showing as image only, and not HTML

Comment: Thank you prash - I have run your code in the playground and indeed it is correctly showing the link.  I tried utilizing the arrayToDataTable in my version to see if that was the issue but I continue to have the same issue.

Comment: can you provide me a live link to ur example code so that I too can view your issue?

Comment: Prash thank you, I apologize for the delayed response.  I am not able to provide a link because it is within an app that requires credentials.  However I have identified my problem.  I am not using google.setOnLoadCallback to load the table, it is loading within another function in my project.  It does not run for awhile after the google.load function, so it SHOULD have fully loaded by the time the table draw function occurs. Even when I wait 10 seconds to draw the table, it doesn't work.  Why would it work when using an on-load callback but not when I am physically waiting 10 seconds to draw?